# Initialize static float constexpr member in the definition (.cpp file) is it possible

Tags: c++, static, floating-point

I would like to initialize my private static member "pi" in the definition of the class in order to tidy my code better having the initializations in the .cpp files.

When I try this error shows up: "Declaration of constexpr static data member 'pi' requires an initializer"

I'm using CLion 2018.3.4 and C++ 11.

I tried to work around and the only solution is to initialize the member in the declaration.

Other answers on Stack Overflow provided me a better knowledge but didn't answer my question.

// .h file

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual void getArea();

private:
    static constexpr float pi; // the error shows up here
};
```

// .cpp file

```
#include "Shape.h"

const float Shape::pi = 3.14; //here I don't exactly know why it does not require constexpr, but it's fine even with and without const 

// what I think this is equivalent to (in .h file)
static constexpr float pi = 3.14;
```

I was expecting this to work like I was assigning "3.14" in the declaration.

I'm not defining a constructor, in that case I know it wouldn't work because the c'tor is meant to initialize an instance of the class while a static member is supposed to be already initialized being a global element in the "Shape" namespace.

What I suppose it is happening is that the linker tries to initialize the member in the header because it has to be done in the pre-processing phase while the .cpp file is used later.

Comment: `constexpr` must be evaluable at compile time, if you init your variable later, the compiler can't.

Comment: the initialization needs to appear in the .h file

Comment: Change your header to `static constexpr float pi = 3.14`;

Comment: @SergeyA that's what I know I can do, my objective was to have all initializations in the .cpp file

Comment: @neilpare that you can't have with `constexpr`. Is there a particular reason for initialization in .cpp file? By the way, your platform **may** have M_PI constant defined.

Comment: @neilpare as I said, it's not possible by using `constexpr`. You can think of `constexpr` behaves like a macro.

Comment: @JulianH can you provide a better explanation of why this happens?

Comment: @JulianH shouldn't be the static that behaves like this and not constexpr?

Comment: The whole point of constexpr is that compiler knows it's values whenever it is used. However, if you do not initialize right at the declaration, this won't be true, as compiler will **only** know the value in the translation unit which has the definition.

Comment: @neilpar `constexpr` literal variables behave exactly like macros (except the more precise error messages :))

Comment: @JulianH what's the utility of `static` then?

Comment: @neilpare https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Comment: @JulianH for what I know the `constexpr` has to be there to make the float `const` so not modifiable and the `static` keyword is there to make the member "global", I'm confused by your previous comments if this is true, if not sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @neilpare `constexpr != const`. `constexpr` gives a promise to the programmer that the used expression is evaluated at **compile time**, whereby `const` only gives the promise to the programmer that the variable doesn't change at **runtime**. In view of the freedoom how the programmer can use a variable, `constexpr` restricts the programmer more, so we could say: `const < constexpr`. The reason why we use `constexpr` is the performance profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `static constexpr` members you cannot leave off the initializer in the class definition.  A `constexpr` variable must be initialized when declared because it can be used after it is declared in a constant expression.  This is detailed in [[class.static.data]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.static.data#3) of the C++11 standard

> If a non-volatile const static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression ([expr.const]). **A static data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression.** [ Note: In both these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions.  — end note ] **The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used ([basic.def.odr]) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So, with that, your code needs to be

```
// .h file
class Shape {
public:
    virtual void getArea();

private:
    static constexpr float pi = 3.14; // we initialize here so it can be used.
};

// .cpp file
constexpr float Shape::pi; // we define here so it can be odr-used
```

Do note that this has changed in C++17.  With the introduction of [inline variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) `static constexpr` member variables no longer need to be defined outside of the class.  The compiler will handle it for you and ensure only a single defentition of the object exists.  You can still define the member if you want, but that ability is deprecated and will most likely be removed in a future standard revision.  The new text for [[class.static.data]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.static.data#3) is

> If a non-volatile non-inline const static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression ([expr.const]). The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used ([basic.def.odr]) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer. **An inline static data member may be defined in the class definition and may specify a brace-or-equal-initializer. If the member is declared with the constexpr specifier, it may be redeclared in namespace scope with no initializer (this usage is deprecated; see [depr.static.constexpr]). Declarations of other static data members shall not specify a brace-or-equal-initializer.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

and [[dcl.constexpr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#1) says that a `static constexpr` variable is implicitly inline

> The constexpr specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a variable or variable template or the declaration of a function or function template. The consteval specifier shall be applied only to the declaration of a function or function template. **A function or static data member declared with the constexpr or consteval specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable ([dcl.inline])**. If any declaration of a function or function template has a constexpr or consteval specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the same specifier.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Comment: I didn't completely understand why we have to write the "definition" in the .cpp anyway (and what odr-used means). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @neilpare ODR means one definition rule.  As a rule, you must only supply one definition of a variable.  Since in C++11, `static constexpr float pi = 3.14;` does not actually provide a definition, you have to provide one in a cpp file so there is only one of them.  if it was in the header file then it would be defined in every translation unit.  C++17 has "fixed" this by making adding `inline` variables (they can be defined multiple times, as long as they are all the same).

Comment: That's more clear now. By "if it was in the header file then it would be defined in every translation unit" you mean that between translation units you can re-define "pi" because it does not have a proper definition? (don't mind to answer if this need a separate question I will provide a new dedicated one later)

Comment: @neilpare You could.  C++ allows you to have the same name defined in multiple translation units.  If those names have internal linkage they wont interfere with names with internal linkage in another translation unit.  This lets you have `const double pi = 3.14;` in foo.cpp and `const double pi = 3.15;` in bar.cpp.  You could compile them both together and be okay.

Comment: @neilpare You might want to ask another question still, but be careful with making it too broad.  linking can be something that gets a book dedicated to it.,

Comment: yeah I saw it's a complicated subject and has to do with a lot of the language, probably something I will see later, but being this useful for a practical use doesn't let me ignore the subject. Maybe not a deep dive but a look will be necessary. Thanks for all the help!